# what is the difference between these two functions and why does one cause infinite recursion?

Tags: python

```
def flatten(S):
    result = []
    for item in S:
        if is_listlike(item) and not is_listlike(item[0]):
            result.append(item)
        else:
            result.extend(flatten(item))
    return result

def flat(S):
    if S == []:
        return S
    if isinstance(S[0], list):
        return flat(S[0]) + flat(S[1:])
    return S[:1] + flat(S[1:])
```

when I call `flat(listoflists)` it seems to throw

`RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

but when I call `flatten(listoflists)` it works fine.

I'm wondering what is the difference between the two functions above, they are supposed to flatten a nested list of lists but `flat()` sometimes throws an error message while the `flatten()` never complains.

Comment: I was trying to use your functions as well, but my Python 3.4 does not recognize the function `is_listlike`. What Python version are you using? Do you need to import something for this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `flat()` is recursive. It doesn't cause infinite recursion, but it may exceed the maximum recursion depth with a list that is big enough. Python does not implement tail recursion optimization, so even if the list has no nested lists, the maximum depth can be easily reached.

On the other hand `flatten()` is mostly iterative. It recurses only when it encounters nested lists so it could also reach maximum depth with the right input. It is a more appropriate solution if you intend to use large lists.

Comment: Of course, `flatten()` is recursive as well, it just recurses less often :)

Answer (score 0):

the second function is a recursive function,python has a maximum recursion depth limiti. you can using the following code to increase the limit.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
```